# Add option to dropdown, backend magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I've been looking for a way to check/update/save a new option to my 'size' dropdown.

```
    public function lockAttribute($observer) {
    $installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
    $installer->startSetup();

    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $product = $event->getProduct();

    /** @var \Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute $attribute */
    $size = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', self::SIZE);

    $width = $product->getData('width');
    $height = $product->getData('height');

    $newOptions = array($width . ' cm x ' . $height . ' cm');
    $exitOptions = array();
    $sizes = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')
        ->setAttribute($size)
        ->getAllOptions(false);

    foreach ($sizes as $option) {

       if (in_array($option['label'], $newOptions)) {
           array_push($exitOptions, $option['label']);
        }else{
            continue;
        }
    }

    $insertOptions = array_diff($newOptions, $exitOptions);

    if(!empty($insertOptions)) {
        $option['value'] = $size->getId();
        $option['label'] =  $insertOptions;
        //$installer->addAttributeOption($option['label']);
        $size->setOption($option['label']);
        $size->save();
    }

    $product->setData(self::SIZE, $size->getId());
    $installer->endSetup();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what are your goals here :) . Do you want to create a custom validation if you add/update an option value for the size attribute ?

Comment: @Chester I want to add en update the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to add new fields to the table for each new value, this is what allows you a place to save your values. Then you're going to have to update the model so that the size attributes has your new options, that will allow you to to pull the current values and edit them.

Comment: Can you give me an example code?